# Path components of quotient space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, quotient-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subseteq X$ a subspace. Is it true that $X/A$ is path-connected if and only if $A$ meets every path component of $X$? Intuitively this seems reasonable but I'm having a hard time writing out the details. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Assume $A$ meets each path component of $X$. Given a point $x\in X\setminus A$, we have a path $p:x\leadsto a$ for some $a\in A$. Composing with the quotient map gives a path $\{x\}\leadsto A$. Since $\{x\}$ was an arbitrary class in $X/A$, this space is path connected.
The other direction seems complicated, as you somehow need to lift a path $\{x\}\leadsto A$ to a path from $x$ to some point in $A$.

Comment: Mmm, as you say, one direction is clear... the other is more interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's possible for $X/A$ to be path-connected even if $A$ doesn't meet every path component of $X$. Let $X$ be the following topologist's sine curve:
$$
X = \left\{\left(x,\sin \frac 1 x\right): 0<x\le 1\right\} \cup \big( \{0\}\times[-1,1]\big),
$$
and let $A = \{0\}\times[-1,1]$. Then $X$ has two path components, one of which is $A$, but $X/A$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$, which is path-connected.

(To prove that $X/A\approx [0,1]$, consider the map $q\colon X\to [0,1]$ given by $q(x,y) = x$. Because $X$ is compact and $[0,1]$ is Hausdorff, $q$ is closed and therefore a quotient map. Because $q$ makes the same identifications as the quotient map $X\mapsto X/A$, it follows that $X/A\approx[0,1]$.)